# My web site still says it is unsecure

Tags: apache2, https

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 server
I am using Apache2
I used letsencrypt with certbot to get my certificate which was successful
my web page is bestwebpage.ddns.net
I get my domain name through NOIP which is configured to deal with my ISP blocking port 80
I modified my bestwebpage.ddns.net.conf as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin wendellkbest@gmail.com
        ServerName bestwebpage.ddns.net
        ServerAlias www.bestwebpage.ddns.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bestwebpage.ddns.net
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName bestwebpage.ddns.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bestwebpage.ddns.net

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bestwebpage.ddns.net/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bestwebpage.ddns.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I also modified default-ssl.conf as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName bestwebpage.ddns.net:443
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/bestwebpage.ddns.net

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bestwebpage.ddns.net-error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bestwebpage.ddns.net-access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bestwebpage.ddns.net/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bestwebpage.ddns.net/privkey.pem
                
                 <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I can't get the page to load up securely.

Comment: Are you attempting to access your website via `https://`? Browsers often complain if you use just `http://`. To solve that what is usually done is that `http://` traffic is redirected to `https://` in `<VirtualHost *:80>` stanza.

Comment: I can access it using http, but https won't go through